# Diphthongs and macrons in Hawaiian

Tags: diphthongs, diacritics

In [Hawaiian diphthongs](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/47050/13885) such as
`ao`,
sometimes a macron (a diacritical mark, Hawaiian: kahakō) occurs:

`āo`.

According to *Hawaiian Grammar* by Pukui and Elbert, we can also have

`āō`

and

`aō`.

In practice, looking through dictionaries, it seems that `āo` is the only occurring form.
In other words, the macron appears only on the first letter of the diphthong, if anywhere.

Is there any reason for that?

Comment: (I can add some comments from Pukui and Elbert if it helps.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually an interesting question, but in order to answer it properly I'll have to provide a brief introduction of Hawaiian vocalism.

Let me start from the beginning. In Hawaiian, like in many other Polynesian languages, there are two kinds of vowels, short and long. Long vowels are designated with a macron (i.e. the horizontal diacritic symbol placed on top of a vowel), while short vowels are left unmarked.

Of course, two vowels can be combined together to form a diphthong. Hawaiian distinguishes between **short diphthongs** (i.e. short vowel + short vowel) and **long diphthongs** (i.e. long vowel + short vowel). In principle, these are the only sequences that you would see most of the time in most phonetic descriptions of Hawaiian (ʻŌiwi 2018: 107-110). We can claim that Hawaiian has eight short diphthongs, i.e. *au*, *ai*, *ao*, *ae*, *eu*, *ei*, *ou*, *oi*, and six long diphthongs, i.e. *āu*, *āi*, *āo*, *āe*, *ēi*, *ōu*. Hawaiian diphthongs have a distinctive prosodic feature, they are all stressed on the first element of the sequence.

Vowel sequences (like *io*, *iō*, *iu*, etc.) other than those I have mentioned above are simply vowel clusters. These differ from diphthongs in that their second element is the one bearing the stress (Elbert & Pukui 1979: 15). Moreover, both vowels that form a vowel cluster can be either short or long.

In light of these considerations, while *āo* is indeed a diphthong, the sequences *āō* and *aō* are vowel clusters. Now, the reason why you don't see *āō* or *aō* quite often in dictionaries (especially modern ones) is that there are very few words that contain them. In Elbert & Pukui's (1979: 15-16) grammar, you can find the verb *kāō* "to go together in a crowd" and the place name *Keōkea* "The White Sand". The latter shows the presence of the vowel cluster *eō*, which has a long second element, like *aō*.

But why are these vowel clusters so rare? Sequences having a short vowel plus a long vowel, or two long vowels, arise in Hawaiian due to (a) the addition of a suffix starting with a long vowel to a stem ending in a short or long vowel, (b) borrowing (like *Kāpāōka* < Eng. *Sabaoth*), or (c) a peculiar phonetic process of syllable elision that I will now describe in more detail. In very few compounds and words derived through suffixation, a stem that is at least disyllabic looses its last syllable and lengthens the preceding vowel. Elbert & Pukui (1979: 16) provide some examples of such phenomenon: the words *moku* "district" and *kapu* "sacred" make up the place name *Mō-kapu* "The Sacred District", where the original disyllable *moku* is reduced to *mō-*; the word *one* "sand" becomes *-ō-* in the place name *Ke-ō-kea* "The White Sand"; the words *maka* "eye" and *kahi* "one, single" give rise to *mā-kahi* "one-eyed, monocle"; and finally *limu* "seaweed" is reduced to *lī-* in the compound *lī-pahapaha* "a kind of seaweed". Therefore, vowel clusters with a long second element have a secondary origin, and some of them can be considered outputs of this phonetic rule whenever a syllable was dropped after a diphthong.

This explains why vowel sequences like *āō* and *aō* are so rare, and are often not considered as regular vowel sequences in most grammars and dictionaries. In conclusion, such sequences do exist: they are not diphthongs however, they are vowel cluster, and are almost exclusively found in compounds and loanwords. I hope this answers your question.

---

#### References

- Elbert, Samuel E. & Pukui, Mary K. 1979. *Hawaiian Grammar*. Honolulu: University of Hawaii Press.
- Elbert, Samuel E. & Pukui, Mary K. 1986. *Hawaiian Dictionary. Hawaiian-English, English-Hawaiian. Revised and Enlarged Edition*. Honolulu: University of Hawaii Press.
- ʻŌiwi, Parker J. 2018. [Hawaiian](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9F2B300BCF6EE97EA7E4437C5FCECB57/S0025100316000438a.pdf/hawaiian.pdf). *Journal of the International Phonetic Association* 48, 1: 103-115.

Comment: Unexpectedly interesting answer to a basic question!

Comment: @jogloran Thank you!